# Excel data shifted in pd dataframe need to be de-shifted to read as pd dataframe properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a data like below

```
Group   node    Amount  PPrice  Cost    Trade Date  
----------------------------------------------------------
[Group1 node1   1496000 99.75   1492260 06/07/2019  
Group2  node2   801000  98      784980  06/07/2019  
Group3  node3   312000  98      305760  06/07/2019  
Group4  node4   94000   99.25   93295   06/07/2019  
Group5  node5   2081000 98.5    2049785 06/11/2019  
Group6  node6   2000000 99.875  1997500 06/12/2019  
Group7  node7   216457  99.875  216186  06/14/2019  
Group8  node8           3080000 98.75    3041500    06/27/2019
Group9  node9           1000000 99.75    997500     06/28/2019
Group10 node10          2000000 99.625   1992500    07/01/2019
Group11 node11          500000  99       495000     07/01/2019
Group12 node12          1500000 100.625  1509375    07/02/2019
Group13 node13          1500000 100.375  1505625    07/02/2019
Group14 node14          1500000 100      1500000    07/02/201]
```

if you observe the above data, the values of the  columns `(Amount,PPrice,Cost,Trade Date)` are shifted in the `group8` to `group 14`

What I want is that I want to de-shift those column values  like below

Desired output

```
Group   node    Amount  PPrice  Cost    Trade Date
--------------------------------------------------
Group1  node1   1496000 99.75   1492260 06/07/2019
Group2  node2   801000  98      784980  06/07/2019
Group3  node3   312000  98      305760  06/07/2019
Group4  node4   94000   99.25   93295   06/07/2019
Group5  node5   2081000 98.5    2049785 06/11/2019
Group6  node6   2000000 99.875  1997500 06/12/2019
Group7  node7   216457  99.875  216186  06/14/2019
Group8  node8   3080000 98.75   3041500 06/27/2019
Group9  node9   1000000 99.75   997500  06/28/2019
Group10 node10  2000000 99.625  1992500 07/01/2019
Group11 node11  500000  99      495000  07/01/2019
Group12 node12  1500000 100.625 1509375 07/02/2019
Group13 node13  1500000 100.375 1505625 07/02/2019
Group14 node14  1500000 100     1500000 07/02/2019
```

i am looking to do this in a generic way t pls let me know about your thoughts how to do this.

> Background:: I am reading the above table from excel as a pandas
>   dataframe, but it is creating an extra column called unnamed6 due to
>   that data shift

Comment: "I am looking to do it in generic way", you do not have to, data cleaning not necessarily should be neat, often you do the cleaning only once (on the fly), then you save your cleaned data in standard format such as: csv, json..etc.

Comment: i understand that .. but this is that data that is captured and want to transfor to other format . if the data is not de-shifted i will lose those data

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "B": ["a", "b", "", ""],
    "C": ["i", "ii", "c", "d"],
    "": ["", "", "iii", "iv"]
})

# replace empty cells with NaN
raw_df.replace({"": np.nan}, inplace=True)

# transpose DataFrame, drop NaN values then transpose again
df = raw_df.T.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).T

# rename columns
df.columns = raw_df.columns[:-1]
```

The input was:

```
   A  B   C     
0  1  a   i     
1  2  b  ii     
2  3      c  iii
3  4      d   iv
```

and the output is:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  a    i
1  2  b   ii
2  3  c  iii
3  4  d   iv
```